# avoid child element of flex box flick on hover

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Not sure this is flex box related. But how to keep the 1,2,3,4,5 stay and avoid flickering?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container .item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your .item class, border in normal position with the same background color

```
.container .item {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: red;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider use a pseudo element for this. With it you don't need to worry about flicker and can make layout without having to take invisible borders etc. into account.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  position: relative;                  /*  added property  */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container .item:hover::after {        /*  changed rule  */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

---

And with pseudo you can do stuff like this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  position: relative;                  /*  added property  */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container .item:hover::after {        /*  changed rule  */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px; left: -5px; right: -5px; bottom: -5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

---

And in combination with `transform`, stuff like this, which is both performant and looks really good

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  position: relative;                  /*  added property  */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: transform .5s;           /*  added property  */
}
.container .item:hover {               /*  added rule  */
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.container .item:hover::after {        /*  changed rule  */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: great, but why not just use transparent border?

Comment: @CeciliaChan Nothing wrong with that, though so very often, later on in a project, one want to do something more with that hover/border, and then, a simple transparent border will be limited, hence I showed these options. Feel free to pick any answer you like though :)

Comment: @CeciliaChan Btw, when it comes to doing transformations, using `transform` is the best as it take less workload of the client device and make them not so easily lag (or flicker).

Answer (score 1):

simple solution but cool trick ..

give a transparent border beforehand so that only color of border changes and no new border shift the content and cause flicker

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  /* magic is here */
  border: 1px solid transparent; 
}
.container .item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  position: relative;              
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container .item:hover::after {    
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px; left: -5px; right: -5px; bottom: -5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can fix it by using [outline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) rather than border.

A transparent border is a clever idea, but if you already have a border and want to increase the "border-width" on hover, use "outline" instead.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container .item:hover {
  outline: 1px solid #000;   /*  change property  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```